# How does Ruby on Rails access the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am using Redis 3.2.0 as sessionstore and am currently trying to fix a race condition.
Since simply locking the session is not an option, I am trying to figure out HOW the session is loaded and saved, since modifying this might be a possible approach to solve my problem.
Unfortunately I have not yet found anything on how this works and all I can find are resources on security topics that just assume that it simply works.

Any help and hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By how do you mean which bit of rails does it? My recollection is that there's some middleware in action controller that handles it

Comment: A race condition on your session would seem to suggest that someone/something other than the user owning the session is trying to access the session.  That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: And if you're talking about what happens when 2 actions from the same user are processed simultaneously, a former colleague of mine wrote [this](http://paulbutcher.com/2007/05/01/race-conditions-in-rails-sessions-and-how-to-fix-them/) a little way back. The article is pretty old, but the fundamentals are pretty much the same

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes that is exactly what my problem is, and I also already found that article. I also found a gem called smart_session_store which you created and that would solve my 95% problem by making the session not save itself if there were no changes. Unfortunately it is not for redis and I am currently trying to figure out how exactly it works. Maybe every request simply calls get_session/set_session at the beginning/end, but I'd like to see it explained.

Comment: OK, session_smarts.rb is the file with the merging algorithm - hopefully not too sql specific

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thats already extremely helpful, thanks. The only thing that I need to know - how does it interact with the code? Does it call get_session at the beginning of each request and set_session at the end of it?

Comment: I think it may only load the session upon first access & I think it may only set it if it was previously loaded (although because of things like the flash , that might end up basically being start/end of every request)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Alright, you're a livesaver. Hopefully I will be able to solve my problem with this, and if so I will close this. If not I might have to take advantage of your superior knowledge again